Stefan-Boltzmann's law independence of surface density
One thing about Stefan-Boltzmann's law didn't make sense to me is that the radiated power density is independent of the particle density of a surface. It seems like things have to cancel out amazingly in the formulae for this to be the case. A dense surface would have tighter bonds between its atoms so I assume there's a tighter angle for emission from each atom, so that would make things close, I believe. Also if there are many atoms on a surface they would tend to be small and have outer electron shells that fit fewer electrons that can emit, though not necessarily relevant. I don't know if you have to think of the field of the surface doing the emission instead of the individual electron states of its constituent atoms. I would think that at a given temperature, each atom is vibrating at a certain intensity. Let's say you squeeze the surface so that its atoms are much tighter, maintaining constant temperature. Now the emissions from each atom must be lower to maintain the SBL. In some way, packing the electron states tighter prevents emission. It might make sense to lower emissions per particle, since they can jiggle less if they are close together (so less movement and perhaps less acceleration which is what causes emission if I am correct). I don't know about emission from a neutron star but I imagine that its surface would have a way higher surface particle density also. It should be possible to consider a surface and calculate its emissions based on knowledge of each atomic state and then show that knowing these doesn't matter. I guess that you need advanced physics for this like perturbation theory or QED?

A dense surface would have tighter bonds between its atoms so I assume there's a tighter angle for emission from each atom, so that would make things close, I believe. Is this belief justified? What is the atom size vs the inter-atom spacing for realistic "high" and "low" densities?

Let's say you squeeze the surface so that its atoms are much tighter, maintaining constant temperature. This is normally not possible, compressing a gas will heat it up.

I don't know if it's justified. Perhaps not. I don't know the exact details. This is more like brainstorming a justification for the SBL. And squeezing the surface you would obviously cool it so that it maintains constant temperature.

The Stefan-Boltzmann law holds for emission from a black body, a theoretical construct which has no atoms or density of atoms. Real bodies are allowed to deviate from it, and have different emission, even correlated with density of atoms. However, making solids denser is not easy, and even if we could make them denser with immense pressure, the expected change of intensity of thermal emission is small if it was already close to the Stefan-Boltzmann value, because it should be always below or equal to that.

Thanks for the answer. Of course it's not easy to make solids denser. However the surface of a neutron star should be pretty dense, perhaps the deviation could be large in that case?

If object has low density, most of the radiation it radiates comes from deep inside the object.

You could take iron from the Earth's core (about 2x the density) and compare it to regular iron. Maybe it's not only the uppermost atomic layer that emits radiation though.
